# Ruby on Rails - Callback after_destroy is not running

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a relationship many to many, I need the callback of destroy to be able to make a connection in another bank and delete an object there too, but the destroy is not executed when I delete an object from the join table

> Sala

```
class Sala < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :empresa
  has_many :sala_participantes, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :participantes, :through => :sala_participantes
end
```

> Sala Participante:

```
 class SalaParticipante < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :sala
      belongs_to :participante
      belongs_to :confbridge_pin, dependent: :destroy
      validates :sala, presence: true

      before_create :generate_token
      after_destroy :destroy_confbridge_pin


      def destroy_confbridge_pin
        self.confbridge_pin.destroy
      end

      def generate_token
        token = 4.times.map{ SecureRandom.random_number(10)}.join
        tk = SalaParticipante.where(token: token)
        if !tk.present?
         self.token = token
         cp = ConfbridgePin.create! nome: self.participante.nome,
                               sala: self.sala.nome,
                               pin: self.token
          self.confbridge_pin = cp
        else
          generate_token
        end
      end
    end
```

> Participante

```
class Participante < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :empresa
  has_many :sala_participantes
  has_many :salas, :through => :sala_participantes

end
```

Comment: why are you hooking into `after_validation` on the `destroy` event. `destroy` will not call any validations so this will never be executed.

Comment: I apologize, the code was wrong, my problem is no after_destroy that is not running

Comment: your `destroy` method is still called in `destroy_confbridge_pin` which is what you want to do on `after_destroy`! also you need to place your destroy call in a controller than in a model as it is by definition an action.

Comment: In this case, I have a relationship many to many, a room can have several participants and a participant can be in several rooms, when and done that relationship is created a PIN in another table `confbridge_pin`, until there is everything right, but when I remove a participant in the room I have to remove also the PINs that were created, so I'm trying the `after_destroy` of the join table, but it is not running!